# Gradle daemon fails to start - Tried all

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, daemon

Hi so I'm unable to start the Gradle daemon process. I've tried all that the internet has recommended and still seem to get nowhere.

I've added the line org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m to my grade.properties

I've also reinstalled my JDK and android studio.

Heres a preview of the error log that has caused my depression

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized JVM option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 
https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
```

I need it for an assignment and nothing seems to be working for me

---

EDIT

Here are the logs
https://pastebin.com/7ehbQanJ

Comment: When does this happen?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: it happens on start up and when ever i try to build the application

Comment: im use Windows 10 64 bit i have 8gb of Ram

Comment: Could you please paste the rest of the log?

Comment: Gradle daemon uses local port, so firewalls or antivirus programs that runs on your computer may blocks and could causes connection problems. Did you try to disable?

Comment: Yes ive tried that it still doesnt work

Comment: Here's a link to the logs https://pastebin.com/7ehbQanJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **temporary** solution is to disable the firewall (or adjust some rules, which I don't know right now). 
At least that helped me. I am still looking for a permanent solution. However, this is better than nothing for the beginning.